# How to generate a hard crash on Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I want to add bugsplat reporting to my Adobe Air app, this part of the code is done and working.

However, for QA purposes I need an easy way to crash (hard crash, not only cause an exception) the application so the bugsplat window will come up.

Most of my attempts end up in Air throwing an exception, not forcing the application to close.

Any ideas?

Comment: how about an infinite `while(true)`?

Comment: That will hang the app, but will not force the app to die.

Comment: AIR Mobile? If so, try opening the `CameraRoll` or `CameraUI` a few times on iOS 7. Crashes pretty consistently on the second attempt. I posted a bug about it earlier today. https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3679543

Comment: Try to keep bitmapdata draw in each frame, when the memory increase at a quite large value, the app should crash

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I ended up just creating a corrupt swf and feeding it to the app, good enough for the test case.

Comment: @Sisnett That's actually a creative way to handle this. Good thinking.